# why two different objects is created when Factory Bean scop is prototype

Tags: java, spring

When i am creating a class object with the help of FactoryBean Class and i am returning false while overriding `isSingletone()` method.But i have specified scope as `scope="prototype"` at bean level.  Each time for bean a new object is creating for My Class.  I am not getting this.  Can anybody explain me If `isSingletone="false"` then why it's creating a new object every time.  Please help me in understating this.

Comment: Can you tell us which factory bean you are using?  If it is your own please paste the code.

Comment: Its XmlBeanFactory